# Topologist's sine curve

Tags: general-topology, borel-sets

When we will spread the topologist's sine curve into components will receive part
$\{(x,\sin \frac{1}{x}:x \in (0,1]\}$

How to argue that part is a borel set?

Comment: Next time you should pose this question only at one site - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279584/sine-curve-is-a-borel-set).

Comment: One possible approach: it's a certain closed set with one point removed.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro With several points removed, to be fair. ;)

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli: Perhaps more than several points! I wasn't looking carefully enough and thought it was $f(x) = x \cdot \sin (1/x)$ for $0 < x \leq 1.$ To be safe, I'll revise what I said and say it's a certain closed set with a (different) closed set removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin\frac1x$ is a continuous function $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb R$, its graph $\Gamma$ is closed in $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times\Bbb R$. Your set $A$ is precisely $\Gamma \cap ((0,1]\times\Bbb R)$, which is a closed subset of $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times\Bbb R$. Since $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times\Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$, $A$ is the intersection of an open subset with a closed subsets. Hence Borel.

Comment: I finally understand. It turned out to be easy, but sometimes the simplest things come in the hardest. Thank you very much.

Comment: It will be then set $G_{\delta}$?